# Necesito ayuda con lenguaje C

Tags: c

debo desarrollar un algoritmo para fundamentos de programación usando ciclo While, el problema dice: "Se desea implementar un algoritmo que permita obtener el promedio de calificaciones de N número de estudiantes."

Lo que llevo es lo siguiente pero no saca bien el promedio y no sé cuál es mi error:(
De antemano, gracias!

```
#include <stdio.h>


main(){
int contador=1, N;
float Promedio=0, Prom;
printf("Ingresa numero de estudiantes \n");
scanf(" %d",&N);

//ciclo 
while(N!=N){
printf("Ingrese calificacion de estudiante: %d\n", contador);
scanf(" %f",&Promedio);
Promedio+=N;
contador+=1;


    if(contador>N){
        break;
    }
}   
Prom=Promedio/N;
printf("El promedio es %f", Promedio);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes varios errores de lógica:

- El ciclo jamás inicia porque la condición de control es `N != N`, y lógicamente `N` nunca va a se diferente de `N`...
- Usas `Promedio` para almacenar cada nota en el ciclo, pero luego sumas a `Promedio` el valor de `N` en cada iteración, cuando lo que debes hacer es sumar a una variable que actúe como acumulador el valor de `Promedio`, por ejemplo `Prom` te puede valer.
- Igualmente, si `Promedio` lo usas para almacenar cada nota no puedes luego hacer `Prom=Promedio/N;`, porque `Promedio` será la última nota (más N) ingresada.
- Aunque usar `if(contador>N){break;}` es una forma correcta de salir del ciclo, si este iniciara (`while(true)` por ejemplo), es más simple y eficiente usar la propia condición de control del ciclo para salir (`while(contador < N + 1`)).

Te aconsejo dar siempre a las variables nombres descriptivos y claros de lo que son, te ayuda a ti a seguir y comprobar la lógica y a terceros a leer el código. La identación, aunque la sintaxis del lenguaje en si no la requiera, también es importante en el mismo sentido.

El código podría quedar:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void){
    int contador = 0;
    int num_estudiantes = 0;
    float nota = 0;
    float promedio = 0;

    printf("Ingresa numero de estudiantes \n");
    scanf(" %d", &num_estudiantes);

    // Ciclo
    while(contador < num_estudiantes){
        printf("Ingrese calificacion de estudiante: %d\n", contador + 1);
        scanf(" %f", &nota);
        promedio += nota;
        contador += 1;
        }
    promedio = promedio / num_estudiantes;
    printf("El promedio es %f", promedio);
    return 0;
}
```

Según el estándar `main` debe retornar un entero, deberías declararla:

```
int main(void){...}
```

o bien:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){...}
```

y retornar de forma explícita un entero, generalmente con 0 se indica que la ejecución fue correcta mientras que otro valor indica algún fallo en la misma.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un poco de lógica, te lo explico en el código.

```
// Iniciar el contador en 0
// Te recomiendo que el nombre de las variables sean en minúsculas
int contador=0, n;
float promedio=0, prom;
printf("Ingresa numero de estudiantes \n");
scanf("%d",&n);

// El while entra mientras el contador sea menor a la cantidad de estudiantes, cuando la condición no se cumpla, finalizara
while(contador < n) {
    printf("Ingrese calificacion de estudiante: %d\n", contador + 1);
    // Aqui el prom es la variable a usar para la calificacion individual, promedio se va sumando al valor nuevo
    scanf(" %f", &prom);
    promedio+=prom;
    contador+=1;
}

promedio=promedio/n;
printf("El promedio es %f", promedio);
```